# Compare hours and minutes to current time

Tags: objective-c, ios, compare, nsdate

I receive two strings: "from"="12:30" and "to"="14:30" which are two NSString objects.
I'd like to check if the current time is between the two received ones.
What's the best way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the hours/minutes components from the input date:

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dataComps = [gregorianCal components: (NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:yourDate];

NSInteger minutes = [dateComps minute];
NSInteger hours = [dateComps hour];
```

Then split the time string and compare the minutes and hours. Another way is to convert the strings to `NSDate`s and compare the dates.

Comment: there is a typo in dataComps. thank's for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd solution as proposed by Aravindhanarvi could look like the following ...

```
NSString *time1 = @"12:30";
NSString *time2 = @"14:30";

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.dateFormat = @"HH:mm";
// ignore time zone of device
formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]; 

NSDate *date1 = [formatter dateFromString:time1];
NSDate *date2 = [formatter dateFromString:time2];
NSDate *now   = [NSDate date];

BOOL inBetween = ([now compare:date1] == NSOrderedDescending 
               && [now compare:date2] == NSOrderedAscending);
```

Comment: Does this solution not care about the day,month and year of the three dates? If so, you deserve a +1

Comment: I haven't tested it, just wrote it down quickly, but it should not care about the date. The `- date` method of NSDate always returns the current date/time. For the 2 time strings it should just use the current date for the missing values (day, month, year, etc...).

Comment: Hi, I used this but I get null.  So i breakpointed everyline and turns out its converting to CST.  I get different times for the time1 and time2 values.

Comment: Check the `date1` and `date2` values in debugger. Most likely the DateFormatter fails the conversion and both values are `null`. Might need to set some additional properties on the DateFormatter to make it work, depending on locale.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)date:(NSDate*)date isBetweenDate:(NSDate*)beginDate andDate:(NSDate*)endDate
{
    if ([date compare:beginDate] == NSOrderedAscending)
        return NO;

    if ([date compare:endDate] == NSOrderedDescending) 
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but to compare the three date I should set day, month and year in the two dates I receive.. quite boring..